# Prestashop disable add to cart popup without disabling the ajax add to cart

Tags: jquery, ajax, prestashop

I would like to disable the popup when adding a product to the cart with ajax,
i like to have the code responsible for showing the popup, i searched in ajax-cart.js, but i didn't found anything relative to the popup, may be i'm wrong.
PS: i would not like to disable the ajax add to cart functionality.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Rather than commenting the entire function as suggested by @Bommerlunder,

I would suggest to keep that function and all the code inside it & just write `return true`

```
updateLayer : function(product){
    return true;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `ajax-cart.js` around line 728 comment out `updateLayer : function(product){....},` Products will still be added to the cart with ajax, but no pop-up will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

### For Prestashop 1.7

Basically, if you disable Ajax Cart feature, the popup won't show again.

In case you want to keep Ajax Cart feature and disable the Popup, please open `your-website/modules/ps_shoppingcart/ps_shoppingcart.js`, find :

```
showModal(resp.modal);
```

Change this to:

```
//showModal(resp.modal);
```

This change will help you to disable the popup.

Here I wrote an article here to help you [How to Disable Prestashop Add to Cart Popup](https://www.prestasoo.com/blog/disable-prestashop-add-to-cart-popup-step-by-step.html) without disable Ajax Cart.

This trick also show you how to redirects the customers to Cart Summary page after clicking Add to Cart button.

Comment: Isn’t there something cleaner than modifying the core module code?